# mySql query - web file sharing program

Tags: mysql

Here is my code. It is supposed to select the name of the person "to_whom" I'm sharing a particular file,
and the whole thing needs to return back the user_id (u_c.to_whom) and the user_name,

so I can populate my friends list with a checkboxe next to each other, that once clicked,
will share (save into a DB table) that particular file to a specific person.

This is from a web-app where users share files among each other.

```
SELECT u_c.to_whom, u.user_name
                    FROM files f

                    LEFT JOIN users_connections u_c
                    ON (u_c.who = :user_id OR u_c.to_whom = :user_id) AND u_c.friends = "Y"
                    
                    LEFT JOIN users u
                    ON u.user_id = u_c.to_whom
                    
                    WHERE f.file_id = 90
```

In the table **files** we have

```
file_id, file_name, file_desc, etc...
```

In the table **users connections**

```
id, who, to_whom, friends
1    1      4       Y
```

meaning that user 1 had initiated a friendship to user 4 and "Y" means the friendship is TRUE (N = still pending)

And in **users** we have

```
user_id, user_name
   1       Jack
```

I cannot seem to get this working for some reason.
Can any advanced user help me out?

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this code. It is an essential code if you want to build a sharing file system.

```
$query_list_count = "SELECT COUNT(user_id)
                    
                    FROM users_connections u_c
                                            
                    LEFT JOIN users u
                    ON u.user_id = u_c.who OR u.user_id = u_c.to_whom
                    
                    LEFT JOIN files f
                    ON f.file_id = :file_id
                    
                    WHERE (u_c.who = :user_id OR u_c.to_whom = :user_id AND friends = :friends)
                    GROUP BY u.user_id  

                    ";
                                 
    $result_list_count = $db->prepare($query_list_count);
    $result_list_count->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_list_count->bindValue(':friends', "Y", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result_list_count->bindValue(':file_id', $file_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $count_ = $result_list_count->fetchColumn();
```